# How to deserialize a dart list into json objects?

Tags: json, dart, flutter

So basically I want to deserialize a list into json objects and save it to a file.
This is my code for my model.

```
class NotesList {
  final List<Note> notes;

  NotesList({
    this.notes,
  });

  factory NotesList.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson) {

    List<Note> notes = new List<Note>();
    notes = parsedJson.map((i)=>Note.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return new NotesList(
      notes: notes
    );
  }
}

class Note {
    String title;
    String body;

    Note({
        this.title,
        this.body
    });

    factory Note.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return new Note(
          title: json['title'] as String,
          body: json['body'] as String,
        );
    }
}

class Storage {
  Future<String> get localPath async {
    final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return dir.path;
  }

  Future<File> get localFile async {
    final path = await localPath;
    return File('$path/notes.json');
  }

  Future<File> writeData(NotesList content) async {
    final file = await localFile;

    return file.writeAsString("$content");
  }

  Future<File> clearData() async {
    final file = await localFile;
    return file.writeAsString("");
  }

  Future<String> _loadNoteAsset() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/notes.json');
  }

  Future<NotesList> loadNotes() async {
    String jsonNotes = await _loadNoteAsset();
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonNotes);
    NotesList notesList = NotesList.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    print("First note title: " + notesList.notes[0].title);
    return notesList;
  }

  void writeToFile(String title, String body, int index) async {
    print("Writing to file!");

    NotesList notesList = await loadNotes();
    notesList.notes[index].title = title;
    notesList.notes[index].body = body;

    writeData(notesList);

    print("From writeToFile function $index index title: " + notesList.notes[index].title);
    print("From writeToFile function $index index body: " + notesList.notes[index].body);
  }

  void fileData() async {
    try {
      final file = await localFile;
      String body = await file.readAsString();
      print(body);

    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

My json is structured such as 
[
  {
    "title": "Title 1",
    "body": "Greed body"
  },
  {
    "title": "Title 2",
    "body": "Greed body"
  },
  {
    "title": "Title 3",
    "body": "Greed body"
  },
  {
    "title": "Title 4",
    "body": "Greed body"
  }
]

The primary function I want to deserialize the list is in the writeToFile function in the Storage class.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Answer (score -1):

You can use [dart convert](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/library-tour#dartconvert---decoding-and-encoding-json-utf-8-and-more) for example.

Your writeData method could look like this. Regard that I also changed the type of the `content` parameter of `writeData` from `NotesList` to `List`

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

...

```
Future<File> writeData(List content) async {
    final file = await localFile;
    jsonText = jsonEncode(content.notes);
    print("This text will be wirtten to file: " + jsonText);
    return file.writeAsString(jsonText);
}
```